# Storing Photos in layer in ArcPad 10.2

Tags: arcpad

I am using ArcPad 10.2 to do some field data collection.  On of the functions I would like to be able to do is associate a photo (taken in the field with the built in camera) to an existing point layer.  My assumptions is that I will need an empty field to store the photo, but I am unsure of what that field needs to be as a data type.

Any help and info would be appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some more testing and, for my purposes, it was as easy as making a field as a text.  When you capture the photo in ArcPad you associate that text field and the photo is stored there.  When you check the layer back in the photos are transferred, and the photo is hyperlinked to that text field, allowing for viewing in ArcMap.

Comment: Just a tip, make sure that the text field is long enough to include the date-time stamp if you're using default settings.

Comment: Thats a good point.  So far I have been using 50 characters without trouble, but I will probably up that to 100

Answer (score 1):

[On ArcPad itself you can configure and capture a photo for each feature](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/QuickCapture_toolbar/00s10000007w000000/). ON desktop, you probably want to set up [an attachment relationship](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t000003vt000000.htm). There are [a set of geoprocessing tools](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000017z000000) to automate most of the process, as are a [set of tools specifically for managing photos in this manner](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Photos_toolset/001700000164000000/).